# Typo3 - add action in record editing form

Tags: action, typo3, edit, record

I'm building a light news extension which should allow sending news via email.
How could I add a custom action for email sending like in the picture?

[image: custom action in record edit form]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the source, there is a hook that allow you to modify this bar to add or remove buttons.

http://wiki.typo3.org/Hook_programming

Answer (score 0):

You can find good example of hook using in ext:news. Look for InlineElementHook class.
For example: renderForeignRecordHeaderControl_preProcess or _postProcess